# Keeping information separated with println

Tags: java

So I'm currently working on a school project, it's very basic.

However as I am trying to sort and print out members after their "rank".
I'm stuck as to how I can keep them separated when I print them out.
As of now everyone gets printed out right after each other making it rather difficult to tell who from who

I'm pretty sure `printf` is better for formatting printing out, but to be honest I don't know 100% how to use it.

The code looks like this (I've left out abundant code)

```
            ArrayList<User> sortedUsers = new ArrayList<>();

            char G = 'G';
            char P = 'P';
            char D = 'D';

            int rank = input.nextInt();
            switch (rank) {

                case 1:
                    for (User user : data.getUsers()) {
                        if (user.getRank().charAt(0) == G) {
                            sortedUsers.add(user);
                            System.out.println("Navn:  " +  user.getUsername());
                            System.out.println("Koen:  " +  user.getSex());
                            System.out.println("Email:  " +  user.getEmail());
                            System.out.println("Age:  "  +  user.getAge());
                            System.out.println("Addresse:  "  + user.getAddress());
                            System.out.println("Hoede:  " + user.getHeight());
                            System.out.println("Vaegt:  " + user.getWeight());
                            System.out.println("Index:  " + user.getFitnessIndex());
                        }
                    }
                    break;
```

Here is my current output.

[image: Outprint screen]

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing you can do is print out a blank line or a separator at the end of your loop, so it will appear between each User block.

Blank line:

```
System.out.println();
```

Separator:

```
System.out.println("------------------------------");
```

You might also consider putting a header at the beginning, with a blank line at the end.

```
System.out.println("User:");
System.out.println("------------------------------");
// all user information here...
System.out.println();
```

Comment: Of course, the next step is to compute max column widths upfront, and nicely indent with spaces, so that content ...well, is nicely, equally indented all the time.